# Optimizing shuffle buffer size in tensorflow dataset api

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I'm trying to use the `dataset` api to load data and find that I'm spending a majority of the time loading data into the shuffle buffer. How might I optimize this pipeline in order to minimize the amount of time spent populating the shuffle buffer.

```
(tf.data.Dataset.list_files(path)
   .shuffle(num_files)  # number of tfrecord files 
   .apply(tf.contrib.data.parallel_interleave(lambda f: tf.data.TFRecordDataset(f), cycle_length=num_files))
   .shuffle(num_items)  # number of images in the dataset
   .map(parse_func, num_parallel_calls=8)
   .map(get_patches, num_parallel_calls=8)
   .apply(tf.contrib.data.unbatch())
   # Patch buffer is currently the number of patches extracted per image
   .apply(tf.contrib.data.shuffle_and_repeat(patch_buffer))
   .batch(64)
   .prefetch(1)
   .make_one_shot_iterator())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I have at most thousands of images, my solution to this problem was to have a separate tfrecord file per image. That way individual images could be shuffled without having to load them into memory first. This drastically reduced the buffering that needed to occur.

Comment: You don't need to shuffle the filenames themselves. `shuffle` is a parameter to list_files and it defaults to True. Read about it here : https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#list_files